# Facebook OG Sharing of Videos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

http://grandstandserver.herokuapp.com/post/yqjl (sample site)

So users click on the facebook button to share a specific post from an share url onto facebook, but the video does not play after the user shares the post onto facebook.

Anyone trying to click the play button on the video only receives a 'download file' link. Any suggestions? I am thinking it maybe the video player as I am just using plain  tags, I've tried adjusting the OG tags.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I just tested this and for me it works fine; the video is clickable in my post and it plays correctly. Is this still an issue for you?